# How to convert a data read from a text file to an array of numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a data read from an textfile to an array of numbers.

I have done the following,

```
with open(src+"process_ids.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

the output data is,

```
['[36950, 36968, 36969]']
```

and the type is of string

I would like to convert it to an array of numbers such as,

```
[36950, 36968, 36969]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a json format.
You can try the following:

```
import json
with open(src + "process_ids.txt", "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
```

Now, data has a list type.